# VBA: Make hidden field visible after checking radio button

Tags: html, excel, vba, forms

I'm trying to fill out a form using VBA (just to get more skilled in programming with VBA). I noticed that the web form is not updating a hidden field when a radio button is checked via VBA.

To be more specific, the hidden field doesn't become visible after checking the radio button.

In my research to why that is I read that: "Events won't (usually) fire when you change the data programmatically". When this assumption is true, what's the difference between filling out a form manually or programmatically? But when this assumption is wrong, what adjustments do I need to make in my code in order to make hidden fields visible after clicking that radio button?

The website I'm working with is from the Dutch Tax authorities: 
https://www.belastingdienst.nl/wps/wcm/connect/nl/auto-en-vervoer/content/hulpmiddel-motorrijtuigenbelasting-berekenen

This is my code.

```
Sub Show_Hidden_Field()

    'Declaration section
    Dim htmlDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim objShell, objShellWindows, objShellWindow As Object
    Dim htmlOption As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

    'Wait an extra 3 seconds so you can switch to the IE window
    'and see what's going on
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:03")

    'Find the correct Internet Explorer window
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objShellWindows = objShell.Windows

    For Each objShellWindow In objShellWindows
        If objShellWindow.Name = "Internet Explorer" Then
            'Find this window
            If objShellWindow.LocationURL = "https://www.belastingdienst.nl/wps/wcm/connect/nl/auto-en-vervoer/content/hulpmiddel-motorrijtuigenbelasting-berekenen" Then
                'This the correct page. Get the content of page
                Set htmlDoc = objShellWindow.document
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next objShellWindow

    'Find the radio button . . .
    Set htmlOption = htmlDoc.getElementById("V1-1_True")
    '. . . and check it.
    htmlOption.Checked = True

    '**********************************************************************
    'I've also tried these options without succes.
    'htmlOption.Click
    'htmlOption.FireEvent ("onchange")

    'Or set the focus to another field
    '**********************************************************************
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple issues with your code. The first one is that you are using the wrong type for your radio button element.

While `htmlOption` is *technically* a `MSHTML.IHTMLElement`, it more specifically should be of type: `MSHTML.HTMLInputElement`. So change your declaration to:

```
Dim htmlOption As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
```

For your actual issue, you should just use `.Click`. Taking a look at [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click):

> *The `HTMLElement.click()` method **simulates a mouse click** on an element.*
>
> *When `click()` is used with supported elements (such as an `<input>`), it **fires the element's click event**. This event then bubbles up to elements higher in the document tree (or event chain) and fires their click events.* <sub>*(emphasis added)*</sub>

So, you wouldn't need to use `.Checked = True`, because upon clicking the input element, you will not only solve your problem with the hidden area being revealed, you are also simultaneously changing the value to `True`.

So you would just use this:

```
'Find the radio button . . .
Set htmlOption = htmlDoc.getElementById("V1-1_True")
'. . . and check it.
htmlOption.Click
```

Comment: That was an excellent explanation but also very helpful reply.I didn't know that a declaration type had to be that specific.and could make such a difference. The best, it does exactly what I was looking for: revealing the hidden field. I also started reading  developer.mozilla.org: Again, thanks for your explanation mister K. Davis. I learned something today.
I cannot find an option to mark your answer as  the solution.